# Unit Testing Pure Domain Driven Classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, domain-driven-design

I am aiming to create a system which is based on pure domain driven design. As far as I am aware this means that my domain objects should have behaviour but not shape. That is, they should not have any getters or other accessors.

At the same time I am trying to follow TDD processes and have come across a stumbling block with a test I am trying to write.

```
[Test]
public class new_purchase_order_should_have_purchase_ordernumber_of_1
{
     PurchaseOrder po = PurchaseOrder.CreatePurchaseOrder()
     Assert.AreEqual(1,po.PurchaseOrderNumber); 
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
       private int _purchaseOrderNumber;
       static CreatePurchaseOrder()
       {
           _purchaseOrderNumber = SomeWayOfGettingAPONumber()
           //other initialisation
       }

        public int PurchaseOrderNumber {get { return _purchaseOrderNumber;}
}
```

If getters are not allowed how do I verify that the CreatePurchaseOrder() methods functions correctly and sets a value of 1.

This is a big conceptual hurdle to me in trying to implement this design so any advice would be really useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Why domain object can't have properties? Pure behavior you talk about, it is just static methods, they have nothing to do with Domain Objects.

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object) tells us:

> a business object usually does nothing itself but holds a set of instance variables or properties, also known as attributes, and associations with other business objects, weaving a map of objects representing the business relationships.
>
> A domain model where business objects do not have behavior is called an Anemic Domain Model.

So, it turns, that domain object should have properties and (in most cases) behavior.

[Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) says:

> Domain Model - An object model of the domain that incorporates both behavior and data

Comment: I assume the point is that whilst the objects have state, they don't expose it: there isn't a getter for every field. That's a principle of good object-oriented design, for any kind of object. But it makes them harder to test.

Comment: This "objects never expose state" thing is confusing and wrong.  If no objects exposed any state then we'd have mute systems.  Which removes any point in having them in the first place.  The "no state" thing has unfortunately arisen from a chinese whispers-like misinterpretation.  The principles of OO state (1) "separate interface from representation" and (2) "encapsulate data with behaviour".  In other words: (1) don't expose the internal design of a class to its clients.  That *doesn't* mean you're not allowed to expose a property. (2) don't build anaemic classes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to follow [CQRS](http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/11/cqrs-la-greg-young/) ideas.

CQRS divides queries from behavior on architectural level (hence the name) and use domain model published events to expose state.

But it's quite hard to grasp and implement properly. Especially if You got no prior experience with domain driven design ideas in general.

Therefore - don't hesitate to expose state, just make sure it can be modified from object itself only.